# Go AWS SQS SDK: How to check if session is connected/disconnected

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sqs

```
var svc *sqs.SQS = nil

func returnSvcInstance() *sqs.SQS{


                if svc == nil || condition (check if not connected) { //check if it is connected?

                    sess := session.New(&aws.Config{
                        Region : aws.String(REGION),
                        Credentials: CREDS,
                    })

                    svc = sqs.New(sess)     
                }

                return svc
}
```

I'm writing a method that returns instance if it is nil or not connected. How to check if it is still connected?

Comment: There is no connection that you can check. `Session` is just a fancy word for a shared configuration in the AWS SDk.

Comment: So will it disconnect ? I'm trying to use long polling so I have to use this `svc` in loop or repeatedly

Comment: That has nothing todo with creating the  `sqs.SQS` struct. When you long poll, the client will wait for the specified time (max. 20 sec on SQS) for a message to return. The func `func (*SQS) ReceiveMessage` will either return after the specified time or if a message became available

Comment: Yes I know what long polling is. What I'm trying to ask is will the `sess/svc` ever fail to fetch data from SQS because of getting disconnected and what errors do i need to take care of?

Comment: `ReceiveMessage` returns an error, that will be `!= nil` if an error occured.

Comment: so if I create `sess/svc` in loop/for each call, is it a bad practice or a heavy operation?

Comment: Yes, you should create it once per queue you are using.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this was to insert a message into the queue with an easily picked out value after so many iterations without receiving a message.  The truth was that I had a goroutine hanging, but I used this to rule out the SQS connection.

I called it a pingcounter and did something like:

```
pingCounter := 0
    for {
        if debug {
            log.Println("worker: Start polling")
        }
        if pingCounter > 9 {
            params := &sqs.SendMessageInput{
                QueueUrl: aws.String(queueName),
                MessageBody: aws.String("PING"),
            }
            _, err := svc.SendMessage(params)
            if awsErr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
                log.Println(awsErr.Message())
            } else {
                log.Println(err)
            }
...gather messsages and do stuff...
if not:
pingCounter++
```

My worker code took any message that was simply full of PING and wrote it to the log, then deleted it.  The session and service objects don't provide any other methods for testing connection besides using them in a verifiable way.